# Inno Setup Loop through files and register each .NET dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, inno-setup

I am creating a setup file using Inno Setup where I need to register unknown number of .net dlls using regasm.exe file. I know that I can use the following code to register .net dll.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{dotnet20}\RegAsm.exe"; Parameters: /codebase MyDLL.dll; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: "Registering Controls."; Flags: runminimized
```

My problem is, there are more than one dlls in the folder and I don't know the name of each dll to be registered. Is there a way where I can loop through the files in the folder and register each one of them without knowing the number of files and their names?

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot find any flag which would register them for you e.g. from the `[Files]` section, so I wrote this script, which should iterate all the *.dll files in the specified folder and for each call the registration tool command line. Please note, that I haven't tested this script, and I'm not sure about the used command line with its parameters, but the basic idea should be there:

```
[Code]
function RegisterNetLibraries(const Folder: string): Integer;
var
  RegTool: string;
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  ResultCode: Integer;  
begin
  // initialize result to 0 processed files
  Result := 0;
  // expand the path to the registration tool
  RegTool := ExpandConstant('{dotnet20}\RegAsm.exe');
  // check if the registration tool exists; if not then exit...
  if not FileExists(RegTool) then
  begin
    MsgBox('RegAsm.exe not found!' + #13#10 + RegTool, mbError, MB_OK);
    Exit;
  end;
  // if we've found a *.dll file in the specified folder, then...
  if FindFirst(ExpandConstant(Folder + '\*.dll'), FindRec) then
  try
    // repeat loop for every *.dll file in the specified folder
    repeat
      // if the iterated item is not a directory named like Dir.dll
      if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
      begin
        // if the execution of the registration tool succeeded, then...        
        if Exec(RegTool, '/codebase ' + Folder + '\' + FindRec.Name, 
          ExpandConstant('{app}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated,
          ResultCode)
        then
          // increase the returned processed file count
          Result := Result + 1
        else
          // the execution failed, so let's try to show why
          SysErrorMessage(ResultCode);
      end;
    until
      // when there no next file item, the loop ends
      not FindNext(FindRec);
  finally
    // release the allocated search resources
    FindClose(FindRec);
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  // if we are at the post installation step, then...
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    // the RegisterNetLibraries function returns count of processed files,
    // don't forget that you must pass expanded constant values
    Count := RegisterNetLibraries(ExpandConstant('{app}\Libs'));
    // show how many files have been processed
    MsgBox(IntToStr(Count) + ' libraries was processed...', mbInformation,
      MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This one looks like what I am looking for. I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks. :)

Comment: Works perfectly fine. :)

Comment: Hi TLama. If I have both dll types in the same folder (i.e. .net dll and COM dlls) is there a way to identify and register each dll accordingly using regasm and regsvr?

Comment: From the PE header point of view, there is no difference between .NET assembly and a Win32 library, but maybe if you [`read the file header`](http://geekswithblogs.net/rupreet/archive/2005/11/02/58873.aspx) and check the conatined metainformation (from a quick view I think it could be re-written to Inno Setup's Pascal Script). But wouldn't be easier to put your COM libraries into one directory and .NET assemblies to the other ? Anyway, it would be a nice topic for a new question ;-)

Comment: That looks like a good start. I put it in a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932165/inno-setup-register-net-and-com-dlls-from-the-same-folder)

Comment: Hi TLama, I have been trying to figure out how to convert that code into Pascal to put in inno setup. I am failing big time. I am no pascal coder. Can you help or give me some pointer?

Comment: I found a [`simpler one`](http://thecodemonk.com/category/wix/) and implemented it in Inno Setup as an answer to your just opened question. It was a bit tricky to work with strings as with bytes, but there's no other way (except importing bunch of Windows API functions which were able to read bytes instead of string from a file stream). Just make sure you choose the right version since the one is for ANSI and one for Unicode version of Inno Setup. That's crucial. If you choose a wrong one, the expected bytes will be shifted because of different size of a single char.